# Undefined control sequence when using fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

I am getting an 'undefined control sequence' error when using fancyhdr to set the header and footer of my thesis. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[4paper,final,onecolumn,thmsb,titlepage]{book}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\bsc{\chaptername~\thechapter{} :} #1}{}} \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection{} #1}}
\lhead{\fancyplain{} }
\rhead{\fancyplain{}{\small \leftmark}}
\cfoot{\fancyplain{\textrm{\thepage}}{\small \thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5 pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5 pt}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Section One}
\newpage
\section{Section Two}
\end{document}
```

Any clue please?

Comment: What's `\bsc` supposed to do?

Comment: Welcome in the TeX.SE. community.

Comment: The error message will display a portion of your code for context.  The command immediately before the line break in the error message is the undefined command.

Comment: `\bsc` is indeed undefined in your example. Removing it solves the problem.

Comment: @egreg, Vincent: Indeed it was the error. Thank you everyone.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by removing `\bsc` as recommended by egreg and Vincent.